# Coordinator Layout - Scroll/Enter from bottom

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, coordinator-layout

I can manage to make a `toolbar` scroll in from top which also moves down the main scrolling layout.

Following is my current solution, I managed to make the bottom layout scroll up parallel to the top layout scrolling down. BUT, the bottom layout is only overlapping the main scrolling view but I want it to resize the main view to only show ABOVE the bottom layout. The same behaviour as the top view, but only from the bottom.

Can anyone help with that problem?

My layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/clMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/ablSidebar"
        android:background="@null"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@null"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvSidebar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llT9"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="...TextInputScrollingBehaviour">

        // ...

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And my custom layout behaviour:

```
public class TextInputScrollingBehaviour extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<LinearLayout> {
    private int toolbarHeight;

    public TextInputScrollingBehaviour(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, LinearLayout ll, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, LinearLayout ll, View dependency) {
        if (dependency instanceof AppBarLayout) {
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ll.getLayoutParams();
            int llBottomMargin = lp.bottomMargin;
            int distanceToScroll = ll.getHeight() + llBottomMargin;
            float ratio = (float)dependency.getY()/(float)toolbarHeight;
            ll.setTranslationY(-distanceToScroll * ratio);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```